# Losing cache headers when serving images with Blobstore on Appengine using Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, http-headers, blobstore

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/blobstore/BlobstoreService#serve%28com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobKey,%20HttpServletResponse%29), I should be able to "append custom headers before or after calling this [serve] method."

I serve my blobstore jpeg like this.

```
import com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreService;

class MyServlet extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet {
  @Override
  public void doAction(...) {
    ...
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=100000000000");
    response.setDateHeader("Expires", System.currentTimeMillis() + 100000000000);
    blobstoreService.serve(myBlobKey, response);
  }
}
```

Then when I `curl -i http://url-serving-my-blob-here` I get the right image, but the following headers:

```
cache-control:no-cache, must-revalidate
expires:Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
```

Any ideas where my headers went?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me just the way you implemented it. Try setting `public` on cache-control.

Btw, [if you want Google's edge cache to cache it](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-appengine/cache%2420mx-age/google-appengine/6xAV2Q5x8AU/QI26C0ofvhwJ), you must set `public` and have `max-age` less then 365 days. Also, `Expires` does not seem to help.

```
setHeader("Cache-Control", "public, max-age="+300*24*60*60);  // 300 days
```